# What do the LUA Hooks in Payday 2 do?

Tags: mods, payday-2

Is there any guide or documentation out there, describing what each of the Payday 2 hooks do. After some research, the closest I have got is [this](https://payday-2-blt-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and while that explains the BLT hook well, it does not explain what each of the hooks do. For example, I want to know what hook to use when the main menu is first shown, how do I find a reference for all these things?

Comment: Please explain the down vote, silent down votes do not help the community.